# How to pass a test using mock on sinon.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I want to pass tests using mocks on sinon.js.
app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const route = require('./server/routes/index');
const app = express();
app.use('/', route);
```

index.js:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const ctrlUsers = require('../controllers/users');
router.get('/users', ctrlUsers.UsersRead);
```

users.js:

```
   const User = require('../models/user');
   module.exports.UsersRead = function UsersRead(req, res) {
   User
    .query()
    .then((user) => {
      res.render('results');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.render('error');
    });
};
```

user.test.js:

```
const app = require('../app');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Get /users', () => {
  const appMock = sinon.mock(app);
  test('status of get', () => {
    appMock.expects('get').once().withArgs('/users').returns(0);

    appMock.restore();
    appMock.verify();
  });
});
```

I run the test file but the test failed and I got this error:

```
ExpectationError: Expected get(/providers[, ...]) once (never called)

  at Object.fail (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/mock-expectation.js:281:25)
  at Object.verify (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/mock.js:108:29)
  at Object.test (__tests__/usersRoutes.test.js:11:13)
      at Promise (<anonymous>)
      at <anonymous>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You've created a mock for `app`, but you don't calling app anywhere. You need to send a request using supertest for example.

Comment: @alexmac Should I add  `request(app).get(/users).expect(200)` to the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call app to mock it. Add `app.get('/users')` to your code after the creation of mock:

```
const app = require('../app');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Get /users', () => {
  const appMock = sinon.mock(app);
  test('status of get', () => {
    appMock.expects('get').once().withArgs('/users').returns(0);
    app.get('/users');
    appMock.restore();
    appMock.verify();
  });
});
```

For more information take a look at [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.6/mocks/)